# Do something when subscribe() completes

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

I have this code inside a component, what am I seeing in the console is this message: 'from component 1: mission started'. So it's getting the response correctly from the service, but once it completes I want to print the message 'successed!!' and that's never happening... How can I do something when the `subscribe()` completes?

```
onClick() {      
    this.service.announceMission('mission started');
    this.service.missionAnnounced$.subscribe(response => console.log('from component 1: ' + response),
        error => console.log('error: ', error),
        () => console.log('successed!!'));
}
```

And this is the code I have in my service:

```
export class MissionService {
    // Observable string sources
    private missionAnnouncedSource = new BehaviorSubject("not started yet");
    private missionConfirmedSource = new BehaviorSubject("not started yet");

    // Observable string streams
    missionAnnounced$ = this.missionAnnouncedSource.asObservable();
    missionConfirmed$ = this.missionConfirmedSource.asObservable();
    // Service message commands
    announceMission(mission: string) {
        this.missionAnnouncedSource.next(mission);
    }
    confirmMission(astronaut: string) {
        this.missionConfirmedSource.next(astronaut);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An observable does not complete until you say so.

```
const mySource = new Subject<string>();

mySource.subscribe(
  (value: string) => {console.log('value: ', value)},
  (error: any) => {console.error(error)},
  () => {console.log('completed')},
);

mySource.next('a');
mySource.next('b');
mySource.next('c');
subject.complete();
mySource.next('d');
```

With output :

```
value: a
value: b
value: c
completed
```

The `d` won't be written after completion.

So for your case, you should add a `completeMission()` function that complete your source subjects.

```
completeMission() {
  this.missionAnnouncedSource.complete();
  this.missionConfirmedSource.complete();
}
```

and call it when you wan't

```
onOtherClick() {      
  this.service.completeMission();
}
```